# Step count retrieved through Google Fit Api does not match Step count displayed in Google Fit Official App

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have developed an application that needs to display daily steps count.
To do this, I used the API available in Google Fit SDK.

All seems to be working properly, but the steps count I get does not match to the one displayed in Google Fit Official Application.

For example, I get 2308 steps when the Google Fit App display 2367 steps.

Is there a reason for this? Does anyone have the same issue?
Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Is it possible to post some code? Did you use the AsyncTask class for recordin the steps in the background? I have asked this question few days ago,but none answered me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129784/getting-step-count-from-google-fit.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the solution.

The Fit app does some additional processing on top of the steps.  It estimates steps based on the activity when none are recorded.

If it can help someone : 
You need to use a custom DataSource of the package com.google.android.gms

```
DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .build();
```

And use this in your aggregate method like this :

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

Comment: This helped me, nice work. How did you get that solution? Any source of that information, or just your hard work?

Comment: @Thomas Thomas this is brilliant, can you help me with one thing?
DataSource is always null, how can I find out the steps count from running, walking etc ?

Comment: I still don't get the same values with this, most of the days returned more than what Google Fit is reporting! It is actually more inaccurate than the way shown in the sample.

Comment: any algorithm on how they "estimate steps based on the activity when none are recorded" ?

Comment: I used this method but i am still getting different step count. For 11 th Aug google fit shows 801 while the step count i received using above method is 838. Close but not the same..

Comment: can please give us full code to get values from request as i was not able find it

Comment: I still don't get the exact steps count as of Google Fit app. I'm using `Fitness.HistoryApi.readData` method to get the steps of last 1 week.

Comment: Superb work @Thomas Thomas. I was struggling since 2 days.

Comment: What about calories ? Following code does not returns anything.

DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
                    .setStreamName("estimated_calories")
                    .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
                    .build();

Comment: Perfect solution. Saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PhuahYeeKeat In my case I'm getting multiple record for same day. Was it the same case for you? It looks bit long before you did, but if you remember it !!

Comment: Yeah there are multiple records. I think Google used some AI thing to group them.

Comment: @Thomas There are still some difference in steps by this process.
Its not working. Do you have any idea

Comment: Can anyone help me out to find calories burn same way like this? @Thomas

Answer (score 4):

Google Play Services 7.3 (released 4/28/2015) added a new method to the [HistoryApi.readDailyTotal](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryApi.html#readDailyTotal(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType)), which matches the step count on Google Fit official app and is easier to use.

```
    PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(fitnessApiClient, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
    DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
        steps = totalSet.isEmpty() ? -1 : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
    }
```

Comment: How would I be able to do this without a service? Using await, it gives an error in the main activity code and changing the await to 0 seconds does not get the data.

Comment: You can't do it without Google Play services. 
You must use await in background thread. If you want to use it in main thread, call result.setResultCallback(...);

Comment: How do I get distance using Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal

Answer (score 2):

As [Sameer Z.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256612/sameer-z) requested I'm posting full code to get values.

```
DataSource estimatedSteps = new DataSource.Builder()
    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
    .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
    .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
    .build();

DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(estimatedSteps, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .setTimeRange(startTimeSeconds, endTimeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .enableServerQueries()
        .build();

PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(client, readRequest);
pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
        List<Bucket> allBuckets = dataReadResult.getBuckets();

        for (Bucket bucket : allBuckets) {
            long startAtSeconds = bucket.getStartTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            Value stepsValue = getValue(bucket, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, Field.FIELD_STEPS);
            int steps = stepsValue != null ? stepsValue.asInt() : 0;

            Log.d(TAG, String.format("startAtSeconds %s, steps %s", startAtSeconds, steps));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you help me out to find calories burn same way like this?

Answer (score 0):

Google Fit sdk is a part of Google Play services.. The official Google Fit app also collects the same data from the Google Play services sdk but Google probably has added a few more code into the Google Fit app to make the data more accurate. It could also be a bug in the Google Fit app.

Comment: Alright , Do you have any specific source or document for this information ? if yes than , can you plz provide ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Android application that uses Google Fit API to access the step count data, process this data, and present it in a user-friendly manner.