# Google fit value is different from one device to another

Tags: mobile, google-fit

I installed google fit app in different mobile devices(android) with same account. After i tested with one device, checked 'steps' count in another devices. But the values are different. I checked with same account in google fit web also, but the value is different.
Google fit value is different from device to device with same account. Please help me, why it is coming different values?

Comment: Make sure that you have the Google Fit app enabled on both phones. That can affect how and which data is synced. Also make sure that Google Play Services is updated. This [ post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789614/why-google-fit-steps-counts-differs) stated that if you use `Fitness.HistoryApi.readData()` method, your values will match or at least be very close to what is displayed in Google Fit. Note that if you want multiple apps to access the same data, be sure to register them using the same [Google Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started) project.

Comment: Thanks abielita. how google fit app storing the data in google fit store? Is it  like unique device or unique account?

Comment: Because i have 2 devices, one 'moto e' and another 'samsung' device. I have installed google fit app with same account in both devices. I did some activities in 'samsung' device then i got 'step count' 27 but still in 'moto e' device have 0 'setp count'. It is not updated the 'step count' value.  Google Play Services are already updated in both the devices. Is it google fit store, storing the data based on unique device?