# Google Fit Permission not granted in very first time

Tags: android, google-fit

I am trying to get steps, distance, calories from google fit API.
I use `GoogleApiClient` for accessing data from Google Fit.
I ask per Google Fit permission also allow to access all data from Google Fit:

[image]

This permission pop up comes every time. I need to allow 4 to 5 times then I can possible to get steps from Google Fit .

What I need to do to get Google Fit permission very first time.
So please help me to solve this issue.

```
mGoogleApiClient1 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this, Constants.googleApi, this)
    .build();
```

2. I use below API to get steps distance and calories
Please tell why I am not getting consistent data from Google Fit.
It always get steps data little more than original steps from Google Fit.

```
// get Steps data from bellow api
private void getStepDataForToday() {
    DailyTotalResult result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal( mGoogleApiClient1, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA ).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    showDataSet(result.getTotal());
}

private void getDistanceDataForToday() {
    DailyTotalResult result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal( mGoogleApiClient1, DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA ).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    showDataSet(result.getTotal());
}

private void getCaloriesDataForToday() {
    DailyTotalResult result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal( mGoogleApiClient1, DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED ).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    showDataSet(result.getTotal());
}
```

Thank you 
and waiting for help

Comment: Please edit you question first, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

**For the Fit permission**, make sure or double check if you follow properly the direction in [Authorization in Android](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization).

**For the steps, distance and calories data you got that is little more than original steps from Google Fit?**

It is stated in the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq#values_for_stepdistanceactive_timecalories_do_not_match_those_of_fit_app) of Google FIT that:

> Because of how Google Fit updates are released, it may be possible
>   that the Google Fit app has a more recent version of our data analysis
>   code than Google Play Services, which is released less often.
>
> Our backends, however, always have the most recent version of the
>   data, and everything gets processed there eventually and should match
>   up after a couple of cloud syncs. Let us know if that’s not the case.
>
> We’re trying to make this situation better by making it possible for
>   apps to request that we process a cloud sync instantly so that
>   everything is in sync, and also by making it so that syncs happen
>   automatically when significant data is entered or changes.
>
> This could also be caused by not reading the proper data sources. To
>   match the value of Google Fit, you should be reading data like this:
>
> ```
> DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
>        .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
>        .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
>        .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
>        .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
>        .build();
> DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
>        .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS,    DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
>        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
>        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
>        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
>        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
>        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
>        .build();
> ```

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414386/step-count-retrieved-through-google-fit-api-does-not-match-step-count-displayed).