# How to get steps same as googlefit app steps using googlefit history api?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

With the following code, i could get the response but with a empty dataset. where as in googlefit app, steps are shown. how to get exact steps shown in googlefit app through history api? i tried for weight, calories.. every time, response is coming as a empty dataset! I have wasted last 3 days on this.

```
DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
    .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
    .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
    .build();

DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
      .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA,DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
      .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
      .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .build();

PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest);
  pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>(){
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
      parseData(dataReadResult);
    }
  });

private static void parseData(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
  Log.i(TAG,
      "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
  for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
    List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
    for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
      dumpDataSet(dataSet);
    }
  }
} else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.getDataSets().size());
  for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
    dumpDataSet(dataSet);
  }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414386/step-count-retrieved-through-google-fit-api-does-not-match-step-count-displayed?rq=1).

Before you retrieve data using History API you have to record it first by using the [Recording API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record):

Your app can record the user's step count by using the Recording API to create a subscription to the `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE` data type, as shown in the following example:

```
public void subscribe() {
    // To create a subscription, invoke the Recording API. As soon as the subscription is
    // active, fitness data will start recording.
    Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        if (status.getStatusCode()
                                == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Existing subscription for activity detected.");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

> Google Fit stores the step data from the subscription even if the app
>   is not running, and restores the subscription when the system
>   restarts. Your app can read the daily step total from the user's
>   fitness history.
>
> T**his exact same question was addressed in the Google Fit FAQs which
>   is found
>   [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq#get-step-count).**
>
> The Fit app uses a specific data source for steps. It adds the
>   following functionality on top of the default merged steps stream:
>
> Steps recorded during biking, driving, and some other non-moving
>   activities are removed. When an activity that involves steps (such as
>   walking or running) doesn't have a reasonable number of steps
>   associated with it, steps for the activity are estimated. You can
>   access the "estimated" steps stream as shown here:
>
> Via the REST API:
>
> derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_step>s Via the Android API:

```
new DataSource.Builder()
      .setAppPackageName(“com.google.android.gms”)
      .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
      .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
      .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
      .build();
```

> Note that even when using the right data source, your step count may
>   still be different from that of the Google Fit app. This could be due
>   to one of the following reasons:
>
> On Wear, the Fit MicroApp when connected will display step counts
>   queried on the phone and transferred over via the Wearable APIs. Other
>   MicroApps accessing local-only data will only get watch steps. We are
>   working on making this easier for developers. Sometimes the step
>   calculation code for the Google Fit app is updated with bug fixes
>   before we are able to release the fixes to developers (which requires
>   a Google Play Services release). We are also working on making it
>   possible for developers to access fixes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

My way:     case DataStepCounterRequest:

```
            final DataSource ds = new DataSource.Builder()
                    .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
                    .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
                    .build();


            return new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .aggregate(ds, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                    .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .enableServerQueries()
                    .build();
```